# Convert .xcodeproj to makefile

Tags: ios, xcode, makefile, jailbreak, theos

I have a Xcode project .xcodeproj and I would like to convert it to a Makefile. How can I do this? Thanks in advance. I'm using Xcode 5.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a one-time conversion to do, this answer may not be worthwhile. However, if you have to support multiple platform, or have other considerations, consider using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).

In a nutshell, CMake is a "meta"-makefile system, and can generate Makefiles, XCode projects, Visual Studio projects, etc. If you really have the need, and can bear CMake's ... interesting ... syntax, it may work well for you.

Having said that, if you don't have special considerations like multiple platform support, CMake is probably more work than it's worth.